# Dust cloud expansion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, explosions

Can someone tell how will the velocity vary in this spherically symmetric cloud with some intuitive reasoning, explanation of situation and mathematical calculations if possible? I was expecting it to be similar to the fluids continuity equation (density is uniform here also) though that was not true. (like when a fluid bubble expands it can be used).

> An asteroid of mass $M$ explodes into a spherical homogeneous cloud in free space. Due to energy received by the explosion, the cloud expands and the expansion is spherically symmetric. At an instant, when the radius of the cloud is $R_0$, all of its particles on the surface are observed receding radially away from the center of the cloud with a velocity $v_0$. What will the radius of the cloud be, when its expansion ceases?

Comment: In my opinion, this is a poorly worded question.  If the initial velocity of the particles exceeds escape velocity, the cloud of particles will keep expanding forever.  No mention was given on how fast the initial expansion was relative to escape velocity.

Comment: @DavidWhite:  I don't think it matters.  We can always just "reset the clock" and assume that the mass distribution started at radius $R_0$, and then just apply your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  A particle of mass $m$ initially at radius $R_0$ has kinetic energy.

When it reaches it's maximum distance, it stops and the kinetic energy is zero.  This loss in kinetic energy has become a gain in gravitational potential energy.

If you set up an equation from this you'll be able to find the greatest radius that any particle reaches.

Comment: I know this sir, my solution would be complete if I get to know the distribution of velocities of the scattered dust particles of asteroid which was given linear, pls read my question once again